# Managed Package - how to update App Logo

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, package-install

I have VSC with Github Repo as our Source of Truth. In my Packaging Org, I updated our logo in App Manager.

1) How do I get that change in my VSC so I can push to Github?

2) I clicked Upload to create a new version of our Managed App. When I installed to a Dev Org, the old logo still showed. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How do I get that change in my VSC so I can push to Github?

You need to retrieve the metadata from your packaging org. You can use any Metadata API client to do this, including Salesforce DX CLI or the Org Browser within Visual Studio Code. It sounds like what you changed is a Custom Application and a Document.

> 2) I clicked Upload to create a new version of our Managed App. When I installed to a Dev Org, the old logo still showed. Why?

This is less clear to me without more information. I would begin by inspecting the managed package in the packaging org (through the Packaging UI) and confirming that the new logo is a packaged component, and validating whether, as I suspect is the case, you installed in a dev org that already contained the old version of the package. My reading of the [ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm) is that the logo of a Custom Application is not upgradeable, because it can be edited by subscribers. Hence you would not see that new customization in an existing subscriber org.

As a side note, if changes are being made directly in the packaging org, that calls into question the status of the source control repository as source of truth. I generally recommend deploys be made into the packaging org and being very suspicious of any need to retrieve material from the packaging org.

Comment: Thanks again David. Very helpful. I found my Managed Package has an Asset File. When I 'view file', it takes me to a File record. I was able to update this File record to my new logo. I'm close to installing the new Beta Version I created in my Dev Org. I would like to follow as you say to keep Github the Source of Truth, but not clear where I would make the same File change in my VSC. I don't think I have any .png files there.

Answer (score 0):

1) How do I get that change in my VSC so I can push to Github?

3 retrieves: CustomApplication, StaticResource, ContentAsset

sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomApplication

sfdx force:source:retrieve -m StaticResource

sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ContentAsset

You can pinpoint specific files within these folders, but this was easiest for me.

There were a few more nuances in my case because I updated existing files in the Packaging Org. Next time, I'd go to each of these 3 Folders in VSC, copy an existing file and it's meta file, and then tweak to my needs. As David mentioned, this is how I'd keep Github the Source of Truth, instead of making changes directly in the Packaging Org.

2) I clicked Upload to create a new version of our Managed App. When I installed to a Dev Org, the old logo still showed. Why?

David was correct. As the documentation says, upgrading the Managed Package to new Version does not update the Logo (Setup > App Manager)